# Powershell - help. Search and name file

Tags: powershell, scripting, filenames

I appreciate any feedback or assistance

The problem i am having is i have a folder that contains log files from all of the machines i'm currently working with. I have several scripts that search the logs looking for predetermined strings, I have another script that will generate a report based on the count of each outcome. However, additionally i would like it tell the machine name of each string outcome. Also, not display anything if nothing was found. Fortunately, i've titled each log file by the machine name in hopes that if it finds the string inside the log it would just have to name the title of the log file it was found in.

Could anyone provide any assistance with this script? I've attempted various scripts using the GCI and if statements to no avail.

Thanks!

```
$items = get-childitem "path-to-file" 


ForEach ($item in $items) 
{

if ($items -contains "SUCCESS") {
write-host $items.name
}

}
```

Comment: Is there anything you have tried to get what you want that you can _show us_? We're not a code writing service but a community helping programmers and programming enthusiasts. If you show a little effort we can help with the rest. As of now this will be most likely be closed.

Comment: I've added in the code, i apologize. I had attempted it though various ways, wasn't going to the throw them all up there.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for putting up something. In most cases we need to know what to work with so it narrows down solution and gets the many simple questions answered so we don't need to waste everyone's time. Welcome to SO. I removed my downvote and close vote as the question is better now.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Get-Content` to query file contents.

```
foreach ($item in $items) {
    if ((get-content $item) -match "SUCCESS") {
        $item.name
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. That obtains the content that i want. How do i make it in a list format? it just jumbles up all of the data, and writes the description for each machine.

Comment: This depends on what do you want in your list. You can change `$item.name` to a query that will select better properties of `$item` (which is a logfile that contains the "SUCCESS" line) or some properties of `(get-content $item)` which is an array of strings (so if you want a title, just output `(get-content $item)[0]` - it will output first line of the file in question. So, what format do you desire to receive?

Comment: Preferably a list of some sort with a header:
Machines with success:
-machines

Comment: Any insight on what does the log file contain (what should the script parse as "machine name")?

Comment: It just lists the possible outcomes that i'm searching for inside the log. Ie.... success, failed, device disconnected, incorrect version.. Etc. And the name of each log file is named from the machine it came from

Comment: You can wrap this code in a following construct: `'success', 'failed', 'device disconnected', 'incorrect version' | foreach { "Machines with $_ :"; ... if ((get-content $item) -match $_) ... }` where `...` means unchanged code portions. This should iterate over your status set, check each log for presence of that string, then output the log's name (aka machine name) if matched. You should result with "Machines with success: \nOne\nTwo\nFour\nMachines with failed:\nThree\n..."

Answer (score 0):

`-contains` unfortunately gets a few people for its misleading name. It is used to find matching elements in an array. While `$items` is an array it does not contain the content you were expecting. Since you are also looking for *the machine name of each string outcome* I would like to suggest `Select-String` which is like `grep` if you are familiar with unix.

```psh
Get-ChildItem "C:\temp" -filter "*.log" | Select-String "SUCCESS" | Select-Object Path,Line
```

There is a filter there that you might not need. Remove if the directory only contains the files in question. That will show you something like this.

```
Path                Line              
----                ----              
C:\temp\logfile.log computer = success
```

The filename that matched as well as the complete line that matched.